# Load an HTML page from local with getURL in R

Tags: html, r, rcurl

I'm trying to load an HTML page from a local directory with getURL:

```
library(RCurl)
my_page<-getURL("my_page.html")
```

but i get

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: my_page.html
```

How can I describe the right path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
my_page<-getURL(paste0("file:///", getwd(), "/my_page.html"))
```